# MediaInfo Output command not working with Automator (command not found: mediainfo)

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, mediainfo

I’ve made myself a nice **mediainfo --Output** command. The command executed in the terminal works well and I get a list of all my the parameters I wanted to have …
But I would like to implement this command in an Automator workflow and I am stuck here …

Automator cannot process the command, I get the message:
`zsh:3: command not found: mediainfo`

I guess it’s related to the fact that Automator does not automatically share the profile of Terminal.app. But what can I do?

(Guess I need to attach the absolute path of mediainfo. But there is only the MediaInfo.app …)

Thankful for any help.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the full path in Automator.

To find the full path, use the [`which`](https://ss64.com/bash/which.html) command in Terminal:

```
which mediainfo
```

it should return your mediainfo CLI path that you can copy to Automator.